# Is there a commonly used root for "Inclusion" and "Exclusion", or some way to specify the status of being "Included" or "Excluded"?

Tags: single-word-requests, roots

"Inclusion" means for something to be part of a group
"Exclusion" means for something to not be part of a group

Whether something is in the group or out of the group is obviously modified be the "in" or "ex" prefix, so the root word should be "Clusion" to mean "part of a group?", but I can't find any references to the word "Clusion" and im trying to come up with something that isn't super esoteric.

Comment: How can they be both? IDGI.

Comment: Just to reframe things: is there something they are *cluded from? The *clusivity* answer is good, but only if this is for generic usage. BTW, naming variable is explicitly out of scope here, so expect a close vote. If you delete the bottom paragraph, you are in scope.

Answer (score 2):

The word *clusivity* is [used in linguistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clusivity) with essentially the meaning you're after. So you could call the variable (or member) `clusivity` and define the enumeration to be {`INCLUDED`, `EXCLUDED`, `INDETERMINATE`}